# SQL Server uses what kind of search to fetch the results

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was wondering, when I use:

```
select *
from table_name
where Id = 2013
```

what kind of search does SQL Server 2008 use internally to fetch the rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends whether or not `Id` is indexed and if so whether the index contains (covers) all the columns.

Often a column called `id` will be the Primary Key and (by default) the clustered index key. If this is the case for you then likely you will get a clustered index seek.

SQL Server indexes are [B+ trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

[image: B Tree]

SQL Server will start at the index root page and follow it down to locate the row. The number of pages read in this case will be the depth of the index.

If no suitable index exists then SQL Server will need to read every page in the table.

Finally one more possibility is that `id` is indexed but the index does not cover all columns in the table. In that case you might see a plan with an index seek followed by a bookmark/key lookup to retrieve the missing column values required for your `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thanks, I had to dive into the following article to get what you are saying 

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/